# Is there any pythonic way (without iteration) to apply a math function in each cell values and then add the row sum in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column(n) | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.3 | 3.4 | 4.5 | ... | ? |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | ? |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ? |

**For the two rows (in real m rows, hence a solution for arbitrary number of rows is required) I want a scalar value for EACH row in `result` column that will give the result in a new column applying the below formula:**

[image: equation]

I can't figure out a concise way to do this with pandas `without` iteration of each cell; I want to do it in one line (pythonic way). Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `df['result'] = (df * np.log(df)).sum(1) / np.sqrt(len(df.columns))`

Comment: For the general technique for this, please try to find and follow a Pandas tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
df['result'] = df.mul(np.log(df)).sum(axis=1) / np.sqrt(len(df.columns))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   column1  column2  column3    result
0      2.3      3.4      4.5  7.415992
1      1.0      2.0      3.0  2.703230
```